# Помогите с ошибкой

Tags: php, html, mysql, opencart

> Notice: Undefined index: country_id in
>   /home/a0226150/domains/a0226150.xsph.ru/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php
>   on line 166Notice: Undefined index: zone_id in
>   /home/a0226150/domains/a0226150.xsph.ru/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php
>   on line 166Notice: Undefined index: country_id in
>   /home/a0226150/domains/a0226150.xsph.ru/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php
>   on line 172Notice: Undefined index: zone_id in
>   /home/a0226150/domains/a0226150.xsph.ru/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php
>   on line 172

```
    // Tax
    $this->registry->set('tax', new Cart\Tax($this->registry));

    if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address'])) {
        $this->tax->setShippingAddress($this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'], $this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id']);
    } elseif ($this->config->get('config_tax_default') == 'shipping') {
        $this->tax->setShippingAddress($this->config->get('config_country_id'), $this->config->get('config_zone_id'));
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['payment_address'])) {
        $this->tax->setPaymentAddress($this->session->data['payment_address']['country_id'], $this->session->data['payment_address']['zone_id']);
    } elseif ($this->config->get('config_tax_default') == 'payment') {
        $this->tax->setPaymentAddress($this->config->get('config_country_id'), $this->config->get('config_zone_id'));
    }

    $this->tax->setStoreAddress($this->config->get('config_country_id'), $this->config->get('config_zone_id'));
```

Comment: `$this->session->data['shipping_address']` у вас скорее всего пустой или содержит совсем другие ключи

Comment: Извините, можете по подробней объяснить

Comment: `var_dump($this->session->data['shipping_address'])` что выдаёт?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/a0226150/domains/a0226150.xsph.ru/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php on line 164

Comment: это оно? или не то?

Comment: или $this->session->data['payment_address'] или $this->session->data['shipping_address'] не содержит ключей country_id и zone_id посмотрите конкретней по номерам строк в вашем коде